# putting 6 sets of numbers on the stage actionscript 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am trying to right a game where there is 2 rows of 6 sets of numbers that are randomly generated matching the 1st row numbers with the bottom row of numbers to see how many matches a turn you come back with.

i think the random generator problem is easy since the numbers are 1-35 use ceiling to get the numbers

my problem is i am very new to actionscript i do not know how to place on the stage the 2 rows of 6 random numbers i have several books i have scanned through as well as the web
nothing i try works.

can i get a little coding help here plese
Thank you so much for your time helping me
Chris

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

See [`TextField`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) class

and [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) method `.addChild()`

You basically need to create multiple text fields and then add them to the movie.

Note that you need to embed the font glyphs you are going to use (`0-9` I suppose)

Comment: You mean `addChild()`, not add.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines

```
        var myArr:Array = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.text = myArr[0].toString();
    tf.x = 200;
    tf.y = 200;
    addChild(tf);
```

Comment: Thank you that helped very much, Big Smiles here